# 2 pc, 2 monitor: Switching between extended screen and two separate screens

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, monitor, nvidia-settings

I have two computers and two monitors: My primary computer: computer1, is hooked into two monitors: monitor1: primary monitor and monitor2: secondary monitor. The second monitor, computer2 is only hooked into the secondary monitor, ie. the two computers share the secondary monitor and I can manually switch the input on the secondary monitor. The secondary computer needs to be running, but I only ever rarely need to see its screen.

I am looking for a way of switching between the following two modes:

- **computer1**: Extended screen on monitor1,2

  **computer2**: no monitor

  ---
- **computer1**: monitor1

  **computer2**: monitor2.

I tried [Disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/) and it kinda does the job. the only problem is that the positioning of my two moitors needs some manual tweaking, ie I have to change the choice of primary monitor, need to change their relative position with respect to one another, etc. I achieve these with Nvidias setting tool. However, When I run disper commands, ie

```
disper -e
```

it overwrites those settings, so it is of no use for me here. Also, note that even if there was no such problem, me telling computer1 to witch from the extended view to monitor1 only, will not make monitor2 show computer1's screen. It will just turn black and not show anything; which is not what I want.

So are there some changes i can do to disper or is there any alternative way of achieving this without the two computers necessarily communicating by simply running a script on the primary computer?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to change `witch` to `which` so that online language translators can parse the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

If monitor 2 is a TV, that is absolutely no problem: just use the "Input" button to switch between input signals. (or use the remote)

If Monitor 2 is a real computer monitor, the easiest (and safe) way is to add a piece of hardware called a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).  Not only will that allow you to use the 1 monitor on 2 computers, but it will also allow you to use 1 mouse and 1 keyboard with both computers (if not desired, just keep these separate and don't hook them up)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but google has already taught me about KVM and that is not what I want. Even with a computer, I can switch between the two screens with no problem, but I want a purely software-based solution.